# Calculation of inertia and friction coefficient of a DC motor

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, motor, power-electronics, dc-motor

If inertia and friction coeffient of a DC motor are not provided in the datasheet, how can I get them?  I need them to design a control loop.

Example:

- https://www.robotshop.com/products/12v-dc-motor-251rpm-encoder
- https://www.robotshop.com/products/555-size-dc-motor-with-encoder-24v-16000-rpm

Comment: Ask the manufacturer or measure it yourself.

Comment: @winny How to set an experiment to measure it ?

Comment: Torque meter. Spin at constant speed and you get the static friction. Accelerate it and you can calculate the inertia.